# Why is ruby warning me over this regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to remove a single * character and any white space from the start of a string.

This is the regex I have `/^\*{1}(?:\s+)?/`

Here's a Rubular link http://rubular.com/r/r5i4FpQdK2

However Ruby is throwing a warning when I try to use it.

```
001:0> regex = /^\*{1}(?:\s+)?/
warning: nested repeat operator + and ? was replaced with '*': /^\*{1}(?:\s+)?/
=> /^\*{1}(?:\s+)?/
```

The actual test still works

```
002:0> "*  foo" =~ regex
=> 0
```

but I can't figure out what's causing the warning.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `(?:\s+)?` use `(?:\s*)` or just `\s*`

`\s+` allows one or more spaces and the following `?` makes it optional, which can be replaced with **zero or more space** as `\s*`